# I can't pull up my reference image's on blender

Tags: image

I am trying to import one of my reference image, but even though  they are downloaded and I can pull them up in other app's when I go to use it in blender and try to import the picture as a plain or anything else, blender tells me there is nothing in the files. I can open the folder's, but it will not allow me to see or import the pictures I downloaded. I had tried to drag and droop and it still did not work blender is not accepting the files. Does blender no longer accept JPG anymore? I hope these screen shots will give enough info to get me back on track.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Shown paths are not necessarily the same. To skip this just drag and drop image file on the Blender 3d viewport window. If the image is in format Blender supports it will find the file. That said if it's about searching file on your drive  I don't think this question is about Blender.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about blender.

Comment: Okay noted I though since blender was the only app that had this problem it would be something wrong with blender

Comment: The second screenshot is opening .blend file dialog which has absolutely nothing to do with images, it searches for the files of the .blend format. Blender supports .jpeg file formats. " tried to drag and droop and it still did not work" when stating that something doesn't work please show *what exactly*.

Comment: Open a **UV/Image editor** window, then drag the image into that window, or use the **image** open option within that window. No, you will not be able to open an image (jpeg or any other format) using the file>open menu. That option is only to open **.blend** file

Comment: They use to be the only way to do it. Okay I will try that thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are not in the same location. "Pictures" is not "My Pictures". Click on your windows address bar to get the actual path.

it should be something like: C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures

Comment: Damn Windows 10 and its virtual folder names!